# Azure Storage authentication via AzureServiceTokenProvider for CloudTableClient

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-storage

I am looking into using Azure AD to authenticate access to an Azure Storage account.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-service-identity/services-support-msi#azure-services-that-support-azure-ad-authentication

```
    using Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication; // 1.1.0-preview
    using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage; // 9.3.0
    using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth;
    using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
    using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue;
    using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;
    using System;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string storageAccountName = "fill_in";

            AzureServiceTokenProvider azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();

            string accessToken = await azureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://storage.azure.com/");//, tenantId);
            TokenCredential tokenCredential = new TokenCredential(accessToken);

            StorageCredentials storageCredentials = new StorageCredentials(tokenCredential);

            // blobs access
            CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = new CloudBlobClient(new StorageUri(new Uri($"https://{storageAccountName}.blob.core.windows.net")), storageCredentials);

            ContainerResultSegment containerResultSegment = await cloudBlobClient.ListContainersSegmentedAsync(null);

            CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference("test" + DateTime.Now.Ticks);

            await cloudBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

            // queue access
            CloudQueueClient cloudQueueClient = new CloudQueueClient(new StorageUri(new Uri($"https://{storageAccountName}.queue.core.windows.net")), storageCredentials);

            QueueResultSegment queueResultSegment = await cloudQueueClient.ListQueuesSegmentedAsync(null);

            CloudQueue cloudQueue = cloudQueueClient.GetQueueReference("test" + DateTime.Now.Ticks);

            await cloudQueue.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

            // table access
            CloudTableClient cloudTableClient = new CloudTableClient(new StorageUri(new Uri($"https://{storageAccountName}.table.core.windows.net")), storageCredentials);

            // this http request results in "HTTP/1.1 403 Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature." 
            TableResultSegment tableResultSegment = await cloudTableClient.ListTablesSegmentedAsync(null);

            CloudTable cloudTable = cloudTableClient.GetTableReference("test" + DateTime.Now.Ticks);

            await cloudTable.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
        }
    }
```

Trying to use tables, results in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: 'Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.'

In portal.azure.com I do see the roles for

- Storage Blob Data ___ (Preview)
- Storage Queue Data ___ (Preview)

Using Azure Storage tables this way is out of scope right now or am I missing something?

Regards,
Florian

Answer (score 0):

Tables are not yet supported for AAD auth.
Only Blobs and Queues as you can see from the available roles.

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD integration is currently available in preview for the Blob and Queue services. Tables service is not supported yet.